# webmethods and web service

Tags: java, weblogic, webmethods

I'm new to webMethods, invoking a weblogic Web Services from webMethods (client), I got this error:

```
com.wm.app.b2b.server.ServiceException: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Connection timed out
            at pub.clientimpl.wssClient(clientimpl.java:2945)
            at pub.clientimpl.soapClient(clientimpl.java:1299)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor71.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at com.wm.app.b2b.server.JavaService.baseInvoke(JavaService.java:439)
            at com.wm.app.b2b.server.invoke.InvokeManager.process(InvokeManager.java:643)
            at com.wm.app.b2b.server.util.tspace.ReservationProcessor.process(ReservationProcessor.java:46)
            at com.wm.app.b2b.server.invoke.StatisticsProcessor.process(StatisticsProcessor.java:44)
            at com.wm.app.b2b.server.invoke.ServiceCompletionImpl.process(ServiceCompletionImpl.java:243)
            at com.wm.app.b2b.server.invoke.ValidateProcessor.process(ValidateProcessor.java:51)
            at com.wm.app.b2b.server.invoke.PipelineProcessor.process(PipelineProcessor.java:171)
            at com.wm.app.b2b.server.ACLManager.process(ACLManager.java:276)
            at com.wm.app.b2b.server.invoke.DispatchProcessor.process(DispatchProcessor.java:30)
            at com.wm.app.b2b.server.AuditLogManager.process(AuditLogManager.java:363)
            at com.wm.app.b2b.server.invoke.InvokeManager.invoke(InvokeManager.java:547)
            at com.wm.app.b2b.server.invoke.InvokeManager.invoke(InvokeManager.java:386)
            at com.wm.app.b2b.server.ServiceManager.invoke(ServiceManager.java:234)
            at com.wm.app.b2b.server.comm.DefaultServerRequestHandler.handleMessage(DefaultServerRequestHandler.java:119)
            at com.wm.app.b2b.server.HTTPMessageHandler.process(HTTPMessageHandler.java:160)
            at com.wm.app.b2b.server.HTTPDispatch.handleRequest(HTTPDispatch.java:181)
            at com.wm.app.b2b.server.Dispatch.run(Dispatch.java:354)
            at com.wm.util.pool.PooledThread.run(PooledThread.java:131)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Connection timed out
            at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
```

Any idea? Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibilities:-
- Connectivity is not there
- Provider is not up
- both are there but processing time by server is more than defined timeout

Answer (score 1):

you are not providing enough information about what you are trying to do but you can look into 2 main things:
1- check the service ACL profile. Maybe this service can not be invoked through an anonymous call.
2- check the port. maybe the port is blocked (assuming that all service cannot be invoked in this Integration Server [IS])

best of luck,
M

Answer (score 1):

There could be a number of reasons for this.

Can the webMethods server reach the weblogic server at all? Try to ping the weblogic server from the webMethods server. Is there a firewall blocking? Are you using the correct port number?

Do you have access to the weblogic server so you can see if the request actually reaches it? It could be that it takes a very long time to execute and then webMethods would time out before it is finished. If it is supposed to take a long time then increasing the timeout can work. Another solution is to implement it as an asynchronous request.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have created a consuming webservice in webmethods. I would try creating an independent SOAP UI project based on the WSDL provided to you for the development of the IS hosted consumer. This will allow you to prove your external connectivity and to the provide webservice. You can work back and confirm your consuming service is configured appropriately.